# How to get the embedding element from inside an svg

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

Using mySVGNode.parentNode I get null for an embedded svg file. Ideally I want to reference the embed tag and its id attribute.

I can successfully search the DOM for it, but I am surprised parentNode returns null. Is it not supported for embedded objects?

Comment: some code would help, maybe `mySVGNode` is not yet appended to the DOM tree when you use `parentNode` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true because I'm not good at reading w3 specs, but it looks like `parentNode` for SVG elements refer to their parent in the instance tree...so the topmost will not have a parent. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGElementInstance__parentNode  .....I'm sure I'm just reading that wrong though

Comment: Ta Ian, for pointing me to those specs. I don't think its the SVG that is the problem though. I looked up the embed tag and I think(!...) it implies that the embedded object may be an orphan, meaning it has no parent.

Comment: @ian: yes, you're reading it wrong. That interface is for <use> element shadowtrees, not for <embed> elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `window.frameElement`. See the definition in the [html5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#dom-frameelement).

Here's an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/from-svg-get-embedding-element.html).

Comment: Ta for the help. I've taken a look and its possible I'm miss-reading it. From what I can see, this works if you are using a window object (or iframe or object) as the container. While, I'm using an embed tag as the container (which may be part of the problem?). Using mySVGNode.frameElement returns an undefined result.

Comment: You are misreading it. You should use `window.frameElement` to get the <embed> element from a script inside the svg document. The `SVGSVGElement` DOM interface has no `frameElement` property.

Comment: Thats fantastic thanks. Much appreciated, especially the example.

Comment: frameElement seems to return null in IE for `<object>` and `<embed>`. Any suggested workarounds?

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg See my new answer to this question, which solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`window.frameElement` is the way to go, as @Eric said, but it unfortunately doesn't work in IE or Edge.

There is a workaround, however, which is to get the parent document, find the `<object>` or `<embed>` tags in it (which may reference your SVG), and, for each of them, check whether the `contentDocument` is our SVG document.

Unlike regular DOM searching by ID, this avoids the need to assign a unique ID for you object/embed tag.

Example:

```
var objectElt = window.frameElement;
if (!objectElt) { // IE/Edge case
    var objectElts = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("object");
    for (var i = 0; i < objectElts.length; i++) {
        if (objectElts[i].contentDocument == document) {
            objectElt = objectElts[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
// objectElt now references the appropriate <object> tag
```

Comment: I'm amazed this seems working well retrieving the correct node element even in the case when the exact same SVG object is embedded more than once in the same HTML document (have my upvote!) ... Also hoping maybe you are the man who can provide an answer to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771696/whats-making-every-embedded-object-contentdocument-unique-even-having-two-or