# What's making every embedded object contentDocument "unique" even having two (or more) istances of the same object source?

Tags: javascript, object, dom, browser

I put several instances of the same object in an HTML page.
In my case I'm dealing with SVG and I have something like this:

```
<object data="same.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
<object data="same.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
<object data="same.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Being used exactly the same SVG source for every object, I was thinking the `contentDocument` to be the same when compared BUT then I put the following code inside the source SVG:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
  async function compare_test(){
    await (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,2000)));
    let objects = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("object");
    for (let i=objects.length-1; i>=0; i--){
      if (objects[i].contentDocument == this.document){
        console.log("matching object found:");
        console.log(objects[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
]]></script>
```

To my amazement I noticed things work well and the object matched seems always be the correct one! I'm wondering how is it possible?
So... **is there some browsers mechanism that makes every content document of the objects in the page "unique"? What is it?**

Comment: related: `console.log({} !== {}); // true`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a specific browser mechanic. It is just that the browser is actually simpler than you think.

The fact that the three embedded "documents" come from the same file is irrelevant. It is still three different objects, because you explicitly specified three object tags. The three SVG instances are each interpreted (executed/rendered) independently. Maybe some script inside the SVG is generating some random shapes? Then you'll have three different images. You need to realize that a "document" isn't just the file from which it comes from. A document holds the entire state of execution of the file (and eventually its inner scripts). So it has to be like that.

Of course, the browser certainly fetches "same.svg" only once, due to caching. But still, it is executed three times, and therefore, there needs to be three different content documents (each with its own specific state).

So there can be no ambiguity with the method you're using.